# IIS Server Config SignalR - WebSocket

Tags: iis, websocket, server, signalr

I'm trying to config for the client can connect to the IIS server, I've already installed webserver roles for WebSocket protocol, but it seems to be not working. are there any configuration that I have to finish to make WebSocket connection work in my IIS server?. Many thanks

Comment: Did you enabled websockets on the IIS?

Comment: I've installed websocket protocol role,  do I need more steps to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, there are no other features need to be enabled. what you have done is enough. Check this link for support WebSocket in IIS/IIS Express.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1#iisiis-express-support
Moreover, some browsers require specific version support.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets
We can download the official document to test the `Websocket` support. It is a chat program based on `SignalR`, which requires us to enable the `Websocket` support.
https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples/tree/master/ChatSample
For more details on `WebSocket` support in Asp.Net Core, please check this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1#prerequisites
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should [Enabling WebSockets on IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enabling-websockets-on-iis-2)